# Exec won't call my second program

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, parent-child

I created a test file to see if I could run a second program, but the code doesn't run the actual file even though it seems to compile.  Is my syntax for exec incorrect?

coordinator.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

// Creates 2^n processes for n amount of values.
pid_t child = fork();

if(child < 0) //parent process
{
    perror("fork() system call failed.");
    exit(-1);
}

else if(child == 0) //Child Process, worker will be called here.
{
     execl("/worker", "worker", "Hello", NULL);
     printf("I'm the child %d, my parent is %d\n", getpid(), getpid());  
}
else
{
    printf("I'm the parent %d, my child is %d\n", getpid(), child);
    wait(NULL); // wait for child process to catch up
}

}
```

worker.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Hi, I'm the worker file!");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are specifying `/worker` in the `execl`, but it should be `./worker` that means the current folder.

Comment: it still seems to not output even though I'm in the current folder as worker.c

Comment: Add `\n` at end of *every* `printf` format, or use `fflush`

Comment: `execl` does not return on success. Read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and spend several days reading a book on Linux programming, perhaps [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf). Your *fix-my-code* question is off-topic

Comment: The `printf()` after the `execl()` will only be executed if the `execl()` fails. You probably want that `printf()` before the `execl()`; you still need an error message (printed to `stderr`) to report when the `execl()` fails.  It would be a good idea to exit with a non-zero exit status if the `execl()` fails.

Comment: In any case of using a member of the `execl*()` family of functions the *last* parameter needs to be cast to `char*`: `execl(..., (char*) NULL);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `PATH` argument you're passing to `execl()`. 
In fact, if you do insert a `/` at the beginning of the string passed as the first argument, the function is going to seek the program at the root of your file system. 
To let it look for the *worker* executable in your current directory, just specify the name of it, thus `execl("worker", ... )`, or `execl("./worker", ... )`

Take a look here to understand how the function works https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-execl/

Answer (score 2):

Let's say worker `executable` is in the same directory where you are running the `main(coordinator)` process then in `child process` while doing `exec` you should do `./worker` instead of `/worker`, that shows current working directory.

see then man pages of `exec()` for other argument, it says

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
```

child process should be like below

```
else if(child == 0) //Child Process, worker will be called here.
{
     printf("I'm the child %d, my parent is %d\n", getpid(), getpid());
     //execl("/worker", "worker", "Hello", NULL);/** It's wrong, check the below one **/
     execl("./worker", "./worker", NULL);
}
```

IF worker is in different directory then set the PATH variable, it seems it's in same directory because you are trying to do `/worker` instead of `./worker`.

**EDIT :**

How to compile & execute :

**coordinator.c**

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        pid_t child = fork();
        if(child < 0){
                perror("fork() system call failed.");
                exit(-1);
        }
        else if(child == 0) {
                printf("I'm the child %d, my parent is %d\n", getpid(), getpid());
                execl("./worker", "./worker", NULL);
        }
        else {
                printf("I'm the parent %d, my child is %d\n", getpid(), child);
                wait(NULL); // wait for child process to catch up
        }
}
```

**worker.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("Hi, I'm the worker file!");
        return 0;
}
```

First create the `worker` executable/binary as

```
gcc -Wall worker.c -o worker
```

Next, create the `main` executable and run it

```
gcc -Wall coordinator.c
./a.out
```

Comment: @noel880 `worker.c` and `co-ordinator` are in the same directory ? make sure `worker.c` executable name is `worker`

Comment: coordinator and worker are both in a folder called "assign1"   This is the path that I'm currently in when I attempt to run the program: ~/Desktop/cs3000/assign1>

Comment: @noel880 I modified my answer to help you more. see the EDIT part, if still not get let me know